# working with Git repository not accessible from dev workstation

Tags: git, synchronization, offline

I have the following infrastructure:

1. Machine A with Git installed; not connected to internet
2. Machine B with SourceTree 2.4.8. installed; can access repository in machine A; not connected to internet
3. Machine C with internet access and SourceTree 2.4.8. I can also install Git locally on C if needed.

I am not new to VCS but I am new to GIT. I want to develop on machine C but I can't pull or push files from/to machine A directly. I can copy files between B and C but it takes time and the whole project folder is over 1 GB so I don't want to copy the whole thing each time I need to sync. 
My questions are:

1. When I make a change to a file on machine C, can i simply copy it to machine B and use SourceTree on B to push it to A?
2. When I pull the latest from A into B using SourceTree on B, how do I know which files i need to copy into C (i don't want to copy the whole folder which is over 1G)
3. Is there a better way to make it work with such infrastructure, instead of manually copy-pasting a lot of files?

Many thanks

Comment: Can you run a git server on B? If so, you can use git push / pull and only have to copy the deltas.

Comment: @JacobVanus : I could, but can you please explain how this would help? I can already access Git server from B but I can't connect from C to either A or B.

Comment: You mentioned copying files between B and C. How are you doing this if they can not connect?

Comment: @JacobVanus : I can remote desktop from C to B and can use it to copy files between B and C, but it's not very reliable when copying many files. All other connectivity is blocked so SourceTree from C won't connect to Git in either A or B.

Comment: You can use git over ssh. It's at least as secure as RDP. You might need to talk to your sys admin about config tho.

Comment: @JacobVanus : This would be ideal, but unfortunately opening any other connectivity is not an option. That's why I'm looking for an easy way based on manually copying files, but without the need to copy whole project folder each time

Comment: How about https://git-scm.com/docs/git-bundle ?

Comment: @JacobVanus : Looks promising, let me read it in details. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer, as provided in the comments by Jacob Vanus, is to use git-bundle as explained in details here: [Git Bundle](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-bundle)